# REST service in Restler cannot find any route after deployed to test server

Tags: php, restler

Restler 3.0.0rc6.

I have setup a simple REST service in Restler in my local development environment. When I have moved to test server, Restler cannot find ANY route.

I have the projects in sync with git via a remote host. I have just pulled the latest local changes to my test server, so the folder setup should be fine.

The error comes in `Routes.php` line 362 in the method `find` who tries to locate the api method matching the requested url. The instruction in this file:

```
$p = Util::nestedValue(static::$routes, "v$version");
```

returns `$p = NULL`. The param values in the call are:

```
static::$routes is an empty array - array(). 
$version is int(1)
```

After this code a conditional triggers an exception if `$p = NULL`.

I have tried the mininum Hello world example and get always the same problem.

Since the app was working fine on my local server I can think of some configuration in my test server that is messing everything, but cannot track what is it. Since I don't know where to start I just include some info in case it can be useful.

I include my folder configuration:

```
html/api/ -> index.php and custom class files
html/api/data-base -> database acces files 
html/api/vendor -> Restler
```

My index.php file

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/restler.php';
require_once('data-base/data-base-pdo.php');
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;
$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Individuals');
$r->addAPIClass('Injuries');
$r->addAPIClass('Measurements');
$r->addAPIClass('Sessions');
$r->addAPIClass('Reports');
$r->handle();
```

One of my class files:

```
<?php
use Luracast\Restler\RestException;
class Individuals
{
    public $db;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = DataBase::getInstance();
    }

    public function index() {
        return $this->db->individualsSelect();
    }

    public function get($id) {
        try {
            return $this->db->individualsSelectOne($id);
        } catch(mysqli_exception $e) {
            throw new RestException(500, $e->getMessage(), array(), $e);
        } catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            throw new RestException(400, $e->getMessage(), array(), $e);
        }
    }

    public function put($id, $request_data) {
        try {
            return $this->db->individualsUpdate($id, $request_data);
        } catch(mysqli_exception $e) {
            throw new RestException(500, $e->getMessage(), array(), $e);
        } catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            throw new RestException(400, $e->getMessage(), array(), $e);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * @url GET {individuals_id}/injuries
     */
    public function injuries($individuals_id) {
        try {
            return $this->db->injuriesSelectByIndividual($individuals_id);
        } catch(mysqli_exception $e) {
            throw new RestException(500, $e->getMessage(), array(), $e);
        } catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            throw new RestException(400, $e->getMessage(), array(), $e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @url GET {individuals_id}/measurements
     */
    public function measurements($individuals_id) {
        try {
            return $this->db->measurementsSelectByIndividual($individuals_id);
        } catch(mysqli_exception $e) {
            throw new RestException(500, $e->getMessage(), array(), $e);
        } catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            throw new RestException(400, $e->getMessage(), array(), $e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @url GET {individuals_id}/sessions
     */
    public function sessions($individuals_id) {
        try {
            return $this->db->sessionsSelectByIndividual($individuals_id);
        } catch(mysqli_exception $e) {
            throw new RestException(500, $e->getMessage(), array(), $e);
        } catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            throw new RestException(400, $e->getMessage(), array(), $e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the Case in file names and class names. All my clases start with Uppercase like `Individuals`, but the files are all lowercase like `individuals.php`. My develpment environment is not case sensitive so restler could find the files for my clases but as soon as I deployed in my test server everything was broken.